# Objecify4 and Spring

Tags: java, google-app-engine, objectify

I was using Objectify 3 and spring before. Now i am trying to shift from Objectify3 to Objectify4. I read best practices of Objectify3 and used DAOBase in the below way.

```
public class DAO<T extends BaseEntity> extends DAOBase{
       static {
    ObjectifyService.register(MyEntity);
       }
       //all the common methods like save, getById, delete, upate...
}

@Repository
public class DAOMyEntity extends DAO<MyEntity>{
    //specific methods to MyEntity like getByMyEntityEmail....
}
```

And i can autowire DAOMyEntity in all my controllers.

As Objectify4 doesn't have DAOBase, can you please suggest the best way i can do this with Objectify4? Do you think writing DAOBase myself would be better?

Thanks,

Ramesh.V

Answer (score 0, accepted):

see https://github.com/stickfigure/motomapia/commits/15975ee0918dd5d7ecc25361eb66b377ce83c2d9/src/main/java/com/motomapia/Ofy.java for a couple ways to do it ...

I haven't made the jump yet but that is the way I'll go when I do...

```
public class Ofy extends ObjectifyImpl<Ofy>
{
    /** */
    public Ofy(OfyFactory base) {
        super(base);
    }

    /** More wrappers, fun */
    @Override
    public OfyLoader load() {
        return new OfyLoader(this);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have seen this one already, but still trying for more best. Any thing else you can prefer?

Comment: This is the pattern I use, and what is intended to replace the DAO pattern in Objectify3.

Comment: This link is now dead.

Comment: @Adam just find com/motomapia/Ofy.java (I posted a new link and code above)